# How to find and replace 0/0 to 0; 0/1 to 1 and 1/1 to 1, occuring in multiple rows and columns in a big datafile?

Tags: bash, awk, gsub, regexp-replace

I have a huge input file with several columns (Column10-Column28) that contains either 0/0, 0/1 or 1/1 data entries.
I want to find and replace in place the following:-

> 0/0 to 0; 0/1 to 1; and 1/1 to 1.

input file:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Sample-1    Sample-2    Sample-3    Sample-4    Sample-5    Sample-7    Sample-8    Sample-9    Sample-10   Sample-11   Sample-12   Sample-13   Sample-14   Sample-15   Sample-16   Sample-17   Sample-18   Sample-19   Sample-20   Sample-21   Sample-22   Sample-23   Sample-24   Sample-25   Sample-27   Sample-28   Sample-29   Sample-30
chr10   60074   .   G   C   .   PASS    ADP=10;HET=1;HOM=0;NC=0;SF=1;WT=0;AN=25;AC=0    GT:ADR:RDF:ABQ:DP:FREQ:ADF:RBQ:PVAL:SDP:AD:GQ:RDR:RD    0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. .:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:..:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.  .:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
chr10   60164   .   G   A   39.77   PASS    ADP=37;DP=20;DPB=20;EPPR=4.51363;GTI=0;HET=1;HOM=0;MQMR=27;NC=0;NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=9.15713;PAIREDR=1;PQR=0;PRO=0;QR=512;RO=13;RPPR=4.51363;SF=0,1;SRF=13;SRP=31.2394;SRR=0;WT=0;AB=0.35;ABP=6.91895;AF=0.5;AO=7;DPRA=0;EPP=3.32051;LEN=1;MEANALT=1;MQM=27;PAIRED=1;PAO=0;PQA=0;QA=254;RPL=3;RPP=3.32051;RPR=4;RUN=1;SAF=7;SAP=18.2106;SAR=0;AN=56;AC=1  GT:FREQ:DP:GQ:RBQ:ADF:ADR:QR:SDP:GL:PVAL:RDR:QA:AO:RDF:AD:ABQ:RD:RO 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:20:.:.:.:.:512:.:-10.3416,0,-25.4805:.:.:254:7:.:.:.:.:13 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
chr10   489979  489979  G   A   516.73  PASS    ADP=40;DP=41;DPB=41;EPPR=5.02092;GTI=0;HET=1;HOM=0;MQMR=60;NC=0;NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=62.0891;PAIREDR=1;PQR=0;PRO=0;QR=999;RO=27;RPPR=3.09072;SF=0,1;SRF=17;SRP=6.95112;SRR=10;WT=0;AB=0.285714;ABP=14.1779;AF=0.5;AO=8;DPRA=0;EPP=3.0103;LEN=1;MEANALT=2;MQM=60;PAIRED=1;PAO=0;PQA=0;QA=270;RPL=3;RPP=4.09604;RPR=5;RUN=1;SAF=5;SAP=4.09604;SAR=3;AN=56;AC=4  GT:FREQ:GL:DP:ADR:RDR:GQ:AD:SDP:QR:ABQ:RDF:RO:QA:RD:ADF:RBQ:AO:PVAL 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 1/1:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:-33.3521,0,-77.8848:41:.:.:.:.:.:999:.:.:27:504:.:.:.:14:.    0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:-57.2363,0,-62.092:44:.:.:.:.:.:832:.:.:22:778:.:.:.:21:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:-33.3521,0,-77.8848:41:.:.:.:.:.:999:.:.:27:504:.:.:.:14:.    0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:-16.4346,0,-55.431:28:.:.:.:.:.:703:.:.:19:270:.:.:.:8:.0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
chr10   489993  489993  G   A   517.39  PASS    ADP=40;DP=45;DPB=45;EPPR=3.79203;GTI=0;HET=1;HOM=0;MQMR=60;NC=0;NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=93.8892;PAIREDR=1;PQR=0;PRO=0;QR=900;RO=25;RPPR=5.18177;SF=0,1;SRF=15;SRP=5.18177;SRR=10;WT=0;AB=0.275862;ABP=15.6647;AF=0.5;AO=8;DPRA=0;EPP=3.0103;LEN=1;MEANALT=1;MQM=60;PAIRED=1;PAO=0;PQA=0;QA=270;RPL=5;RPP=4.09604;RPR=3;RUN=1;SAF=5;SAP=4.09604;SAR=3;AN=56;AC=4  GT:RDF:ABQ:QR:ADF:RBQ:AO:PVAL:RD:QA:RO:ADR:DP:FREQ:GL:GQ:AD:SDP:RDR 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:.:900:.:.:20:.:.:687:25:.:45:.:-48.5936,0,-67.7665:.:.:.:.    0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:.:834:.:.:22:.:.:784:22:.:45:.:-57.4791,0,-61.9781:.:.:.:.    0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:.:900:.:.:20:.:.:687:25:.:45:.:-48.5936,0,-67.7665:.:.:.:.    0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:.:777:.:.:8:.:.:270:21:.:29:.:-15.8938,0,-58.4546:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
chr10   490056  .   T   C   612.45  PASS    ADP=59;DP=69;DPB=69;EPPR=6.8707;GTI=0;HET=1;HOM=0;MQMR=59.75;NC=0;NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=141.021;PAIREDR=1;PQR=0;PRO=0;QR=1092;RO=36;RPPR=3.25157;SF=0,1;SRF=19;SRP=3.25157;SRR=17;WT=0;AB=0.486486;ABP=3.06899;AF=0.5;AO=18;DPRA=0;EPP=33.8935;LEN=1;MEANALT=1;MQM=57.5;PAIRED=1;PAO=0;PQA=0;QA=634;RPL=18;RPP=7.35324;RPR=5;RUN=1;SAF=11;SAP=4.9405;SAR=7;AN=56;AC=3  GT:SDP:FREQ:RBQ:RDR:RDF:GL:RO:ADR:ADF:QR:AD:RD:ABQ:PVAL:AO:QA:GQ:DP 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:.:.:.:.:-69.4469,0,-78.8411:36:.:.:1092:.:.:.:.:29:997:.:69   0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:.:.:.:.:-60.0267,0,-33.0544:15:.:.:491:.:.:.:.:23:799:.:38    0/0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:.:.:.:.:.:-10,0,-10:19:.:.:580:.:.:.:.:18:634:.:37
```

output file:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Sample-1    Sample-2    Sample-3    Sample-4    Sample-5    Sample-7    Sample-8    Sample-9    Sample-10   Sample-11   Sample-12   Sample-13   Sample-14   Sample-15   Sample-16   Sample-17   Sample-18   Sample-19   Sample-20   Sample-21   Sample-22   Sample-23   Sample-24   Sample-25   Sample-27   Sample-28   Sample-29   Sample-30
chr10   60074   .   G   C   .   PASS    ADP=10;HET=1;HOM=0;NC=0;SF=1;WT=0;AN=25;AC=0    GT:ADR:RDF:ABQ:DP:FREQ:ADF:RBQ:PVAL:SDP:AD:GQ:RDR:RD    0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. .:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:..:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.  .:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:. 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
chr10   60164   .   G   A   39.77   PASS    ADP=37;DP=20;DPB=20;EPPR=4.51363;GTI=0;HET=1;HOM=0;MQMR=27;NC=0;NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=9.15713;PAIREDR=1;PQR=0;PRO=0;QR=512;RO=13;RPPR=4.51363;SF=0,1;SRF=13;SRP=31.2394;SRR=0;WT=0;AB=0.35;ABP=6.91895;AF=0.5;AO=7;DPRA=0;EPP=3.32051;LEN=1;MEANALT=1;MQM=27;PAIRED=1;PAO=0;PQA=0;QA=254;RPL=3;RPP=3.32051;RPR=4;RUN=1;SAF=7;SAP=18.2106;SAR=0;AN=56;AC=1  GT:FREQ:DP:GQ:RBQ:ADF:ADR:QR:SDP:GL:PVAL:RDR:QA:AO:RDF:AD:ABQ:RD:RO 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:20:.:.:.:.:512:.:-10.3416,0,-25.4805:.:.:254:7:.:.:.:.:13   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
chr10   489979  489979  G   A   516.73  PASS    ADP=40;DP=41;DPB=41;EPPR=5.02092;GTI=0;HET=1;HOM=0;MQMR=60;NC=0;NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=62.0891;PAIREDR=1;PQR=0;PRO=0;QR=999;RO=27;RPPR=3.09072;SF=0,1;SRF=17;SRP=6.95112;SRR=10;WT=0;AB=0.285714;ABP=14.1779;AF=0.5;AO=8;DPRA=0;EPP=3.0103;LEN=1;MEANALT=2;MQM=60;PAIRED=1;PAO=0;PQA=0;QA=270;RPL=3;RPP=4.09604;RPR=5;RUN=1;SAF=5;SAP=4.09604;SAR=3;AN=56;AC=4  GT:FREQ:GL:DP:ADR:RDR:GQ:AD:SDP:QR:ABQ:RDF:RO:QA:RD:ADF:RBQ:AO:PVAL 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:-33.3521,0,-77.8848:41:.:.:.:.:.:999:.:.:27:504:.:.:.:14:.  0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:-57.2363,0,-62.092:44:.:.:.:.:.:832:.:.:22:778:.:.:.:21:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:-33.3521,0,-77.8848:41:.:.:.:.:.:999:.:.:27:504:.:.:.:14:.  0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:-16.4346,0,-55.431:28:.:.:.:.:.:703:.:.:19:270:.:.:.:8:.0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
chr10   489993  489993  G   A   517.39  PASS    ADP=40;DP=45;DPB=45;EPPR=3.79203;GTI=0;HET=1;HOM=0;MQMR=60;NC=0;NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=93.8892;PAIREDR=1;PQR=0;PRO=0;QR=900;RO=25;RPPR=5.18177;SF=0,1;SRF=15;SRP=5.18177;SRR=10;WT=0;AB=0.275862;ABP=15.6647;AF=0.5;AO=8;DPRA=0;EPP=3.0103;LEN=1;MEANALT=1;MQM=60;PAIRED=1;PAO=0;PQA=0;QA=270;RPL=5;RPP=4.09604;RPR=3;RUN=1;SAF=5;SAP=4.09604;SAR=3;AN=56;AC=4  GT:RDF:ABQ:QR:ADF:RBQ:AO:PVAL:RD:QA:RO:ADR:DP:FREQ:GL:GQ:AD:SDP:RDR 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:.:900:.:.:20:.:.:687:25:.:45:.:-48.5936,0,-67.7665:.:.:.:.  0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:.:834:.:.:22:.:.:784:22:.:45:.:-57.4791,0,-61.9781:.:.:.:.  0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:.:900:.:.:20:.:.:687:25:.:45:.:-48.5936,0,-67.7665:.:.:.:.  0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:.:777:.:.:8:.:.:270:21:.:29:.:-15.8938,0,-58.4546:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
chr10   490056  .   T   C   612.45  PASS    ADP=59;DP=69;DPB=69;EPPR=6.8707;GTI=0;HET=1;HOM=0;MQMR=59.75;NC=0;NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=141.021;PAIREDR=1;PQR=0;PRO=0;QR=1092;RO=36;RPPR=3.25157;SF=0,1;SRF=19;SRP=3.25157;SRR=17;WT=0;AB=0.486486;ABP=3.06899;AF=0.5;AO=18;DPRA=0;EPP=33.8935;LEN=1;MEANALT=1;MQM=57.5;PAIRED=1;PAO=0;PQA=0;QA=634;RPL=18;RPP=7.35324;RPR=5;RUN=1;SAF=11;SAP=4.9405;SAR=7;AN=56;AC=3  GT:SDP:FREQ:RBQ:RDR:RDF:GL:RO:ADR:ADF:QR:AD:RD:ABQ:PVAL:AO:QA:GQ:DP 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:.:.:.:.:-69.4469,0,-78.8411:36:.:.:1092:.:.:.:.:29:997:.:69 0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:.:.:.:.:-60.0267,0,-33.0544:15:.:.:491:.:.:.:.:23:799:.:38  0:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.   1:.:.:.:.:.:-10,0,-10:19:.:.:580:.:.:.:.:18:634:.:37
```

Can anyone please suggest an easy approach, perhaps awk + gsub command??

Comment: Is it possible to have values `1/0` or values such as `10/10` etc?

Comment: No there are no 1/0 or 10/10 values. There are values such as 10, 100 etc in other columns. I want to incur the substitution only among columns 10 to columns 28. And there are only 0/0 or 0/1 or 1/1.

Comment: is it possible for the strings (`0/0`, `0/1`, `1/1`) to show up in columns 1-9 and/or 29-EOL

Comment: No, they appear only in columns 10 to columns 28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 0/0 to 0; 0/1 to 1; and 1/1 to 1.

Observation: in each case you want replace expression by what is after `/`. I would harness GNU `sed` for this task following way, for brevity sake I would use `file.txt` as follows

```
text 0/0 text
text 0/1 text
text 1/1 text
text text text
text 0/0 text 0/1 text 1/1 text
```

then

```
sed 's|[01]/\([01]\)|\1|g' file.txt
```

gives output

```
text 0 text
text 1 text
text 1 text
text text text
text 0 text 1 text 1 text
```

Explanation: I elected to use `|` rather than `/` to avoid need of escaping latter, as you have literal `/`. I use capturing group to substitute (`s`) `0` or `1` followed by `/` followed by `0` or `1` using last part (`0` or `1` after `/`) and do it globally (`g`) to apply such change for all occurences in each line.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*

Comment: Awesome   !! Many thanks for helping out. I appreciate very much your explanation. Your suggestion worked smoothly, superfast on all bigfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it with

```
sed 's/0\/0/0/g' file | sed 's/0\/1/1/g' | sed 's/1\/1/1/g'
```

Comment: I tried this `sed -i 's/SEARCH_REGEX/REPLACEMENT/g' INPUTFILE` and it didn't work. Also your suggestion did not work.

Comment: I tried this `sed -i 's/SEARCH_REGEX/REPLACEMENT/g' INPUTFILE` .   Here SEARCH_REGEX is 0/0 or 0/1 or 1/1 AND REPLACEMENT is 0 or 1 or 1, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it :

> ```
> {m,g}awk ++NF OFS= FS='[01]/'
> ```

Comment: While working answers are nice, explanations of what a succinct command does would help others understand what is going on.

Comment: @herrbischoff : the desired outcomes of the 3 scenarios mentioned by OP are simply the 2nd half of the number pair - this merely chops off the first half, nothing more.